# probability distribution of an infinite dimensional variable?

Tags: probability-theory

In university level probability, we start out with a one-dimensional random variable $X$, that has a probability distribution $f(x):\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$

Then we move up the ladder, to multi-dimensional random variables with probability distribution $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$

**Now I'm wondering, how do we model probability distributions of countably infinite dimensional random variables? And uncountable-of-degree-1 dimensional random variables? and uncountable-of-degree-2...?**

Comment: I think you mean continuous/discrete time stochastic processes. Here, the measure is on (infinite dimensional) function spaces (with appropriate $\sigma$-algebra) instead of the Euclidean space.

Comment: As mentioned above, an example would be the Brownian motion, which is like a Gaussian random variable with an index set with uncountable cardinality. You may want to look up words like random fields, Gaussian process, etc.